# how to add string or an of characters in mysql while using group by function

Tags: mysql, oracle, oracle-apex

For example, I have a table named XYZ and it has a column COUNTRY, how can I take out results in the following format using group by function,

INDIA has 3 employees

here 3 is opted from count() and INDIA is grouped by "GROUP BY", my question is that how do you print 'has' and employees in between and at the end in mySQl

I am learning DBMS in Oracle APEX.
THANKS.

Comment: I have tried this but not getting what i want



Select distinct COUNTRY
from XYZ
group by Country
order by count(*) desc

Comment: Each make and version of database server has its own dialect of SQL. Please [edit] your question to add a [tag](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database you use. [tag:mysql]?  [tag:oracle]? Another?

Comment: If you are using Oracle APEX you can't be using MySQL - which one is it really?

Comment: i am using oracle apex which uses sql commands

Comment: Note that "mysql" is a different product. "sql" and "mysql" are no synonyms. "mysql" is a relational database, just like "oracle", "mariadb", "sql server" and others. "sql" is the language all these databases use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL / MariaDB you want

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', country, 'has', COUNT(*), 'employees')
```

In Oracle you want

```
SELECT country || ' has ' || COUNT(*) || ' employees
```

**Edit**  This is plain old string processing. Every language, including every SQL dialect, has its own ways of doing string processing.

You can generate any sort of string you want, either with Oracle's `||` or MariaDB / MySQL's [CONCAT_WS()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws). For your example, it's

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', COUNT(*), 'employees from', country)
```

or

```
SELECT COUNT(*) || ' employees from ' || country
```

Comment: Thank you - I didn't know of `CONCAT_WS`. (Here it's not a problem but I can see the usefulness in other situations.) I'll remember that CONCAT With Seperator

Comment: What if I want it like this 3 employees from India?

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle we can use `||` to concatenate strings in the ***SELECT***.
If we want to list all the values in a ***GROUP BY*** we can use `LISTAGG()`.
( In mySQL we can use `CONCAT()` or `CONCAT_WS()` for simple concatenation and `GROUP_CONCAT()` with GROUP BY. )

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Employee (
> id int, 
> name varchar(10),
> country varchar(10));
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (1,'Tom','India');
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (2,'Dick','India');
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (3,'Harry','India');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT country || ' has ' || COUNT(id) ||  ' employees' AS report
> FROM Employee
> GROUP BY country;
> ```
>
> ```
> | REPORT                |
> | :-------------------- |
> | India has 3 employees |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT country, LISTAGG(name,', ') Employees
> FROM Employee
> GROUP BY country;
> ```
>
> ```
> COUNTRY | EMPLOYEES       
> :------ | :---------------
> India   | Tom, Dick, Harry
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c759a55be94ab233037b2e23cd655b9b)*

Comment: One more thing, What if I want it like this
3 employees from India

Comment: Please see modified answer with `LISTAGG()` added.